# Spring social siginIn() not firing on successful authentication

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-security, spring-social

I've implemented Spring Social and have successfully been able to implement the ProviderSignInController to authenticate connections to Facebook.

As part of this I needed to implement the SignInAdapter interface. I understand this interface is used in the final steps of a successful authentication with a provider, specifically I'm overriding the signIn method to log the client into my application programmatically after successful authentication with the provider.

My problem is that when I implement the SignInAdapter it doesn't fire the signIn() method on successful login.

The code is almost straight out of the [Spring showcase examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/showcase/signin):

```
public class SimpleSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleSignInAdapter.class);
    private final RequestCache requestCache;

    @Inject
    public SimpleSignInAdapter(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
        logger.debug("Constructing " + SimpleSignInAdapter.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public String signIn(String localUserId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
        /* A social profile has been found. Now we need to log that user into the 
         * application programatically.
         * 
         * No other credentials are necessary here because by the time this method 
         * is called the user will have signed into the provider and their connection 
         * with that provider has been used to prove the user's identity.
         */
        logger.debug("A social profile has been found. Now we need to log that user into the app.");
        SignInUtils.signin(localUserId);
        return null;
    }

    private String extractOriginalUrl(NativeWebRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest nativeReq = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse nativeRes = request.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
        SavedRequest saved = requestCache.getRequest(nativeReq, nativeRes);
        if (saved == null) {
            return null;
        }
        requestCache.removeRequest(nativeReq, nativeRes);
        removeAutheticationAttributes(nativeReq.getSession(false));
        return saved.getRedirectUrl();
    }

    private void removeAutheticationAttributes(HttpSession session) {
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }

}
```

The interesting this is that the SimpleSignInAdapter is constructed as I can debug through that step and see my debug output in the log so it seems the Bean is being instantiated just not firing the signIn method.

Here's my Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.webclient")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-app-context.xml")
public class MainConfig {
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

And my Spring Social config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

        private SocialUserDAO socialUserDao;
        //
        // SocialConfigurer implementation methods
        //

        @Override
        public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
            cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory("XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXX"));
            cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory("XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXX"));
        }

        @Override
        public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
                return new UserIdSource() {                        
                        @Override
                        public String getUserId() {
                                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                                if (authentication == null) {
                                        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                                }
                                return authentication.getName();
                        }
                };
        }

        @Override
        public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
                return new HibernateUsersConnectionRepository(socialUserDao, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
        }

        //
        // API Binding Beans
        //

        @Bean
        @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
        public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository repository) {
                Connection<Facebook> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
                return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
        public Twitter twitter(ConnectionRepository repository) {
                Connection<Twitter> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
                return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
        public LinkedIn linkedin(ConnectionRepository repository) {
                Connection<LinkedIn> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class);
                return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
        }

        //
        // Web Controller and Filter Beans
        //
        @Bean
        public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
                ConnectController connectController = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
                connectController.addInterceptor(new PostToWallAfterConnectInterceptor());
                connectController.addInterceptor(new TweetAfterConnectInterceptor());
                return connectController;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
                return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new SimpleSignInAdapter(new HttpSessionRequestCache()));
        }

        @Bean
        public DisconnectController disconnectController(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, Environment env) {
                return new DisconnectController(usersConnectionRepository, env.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret"));
        }

        @Bean
        public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, UserIdSource userIdSource) {
                return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
        }

}
```

Is there any way for me to confirm why the signIn() is not being fired or even if it is being registered.

Comment: Could you paste the code of your sign in controller ?